# Изменение падежа дополнения при отрицании глагола

Tags: согласование, падежи

Обратил внимание на необычную (на мой взгляд) закономерность. Мы говорим `делай что-то`, вопрос `что?`, винительный падеж. Но при отрицании возможны два варианта: `не делай (что?) это` (Вн.п) и `не делай (чего?) этого` (Рд.п). Разве падеж дополнения не должен зависеть *только* от семантического отношения с глаголом? Наверное, это просто устоявшейся в речи оборот? Или можно найти аналогичные случаи?

Comment: вот здесь почитайте  : http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/202/%D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?

Существительное, относящееся к глаголу с отрицанием, может иметь форму родительного или винительного падежа, например: **не прочитал этой статьи – не прочитал эту статью.** Трудность заключается в том, что в одних случаях тот или иной падеж является предпочтительным, а в других существует равная возможность употребления как родительного, так и винительного падежа.
Когда нужен родительный падеж?

При сочетании с глаголом не иметь: **не имеет права, значения, смысла, намерения, понятия, влияния; не имеет дома, денег, машины, брата, друга, сведений.**

При наличии слов никакой, ничей, ни один:  не взял на себя никакой ответственности, не потерял ни одного грамма, не прочитал ни одной статьи.
    При глаголах восприятия, мысли: **не понял вопроса, не знал урока, не чувствовал боли, не заметил ошибки, не видел дорожного знака.**

> Если существительное имеет отвлеченное значение: не теряет времени, не испытывает желания, не скрывает радости.
>   Если в качестве зависимого слова используется местоимение: не допущу этого; не делайте того.
>     Если перед глаголом или непосредственно перед именем есть усилительные частицы **и, даже:**

**Отправлялись за покупками втроем, но Любе и слова сказать не удавалось, старики сами все выбирали (Кетл.); Руки дрожат и не держат даже плошки с лекарством - не удержать им и книги (Сарт.); На тротуарах тесно, но никто вас не толкнет, никто ни с кем не ссорится, не услышишь даже громкого слова (газ.)**

При наличии повторяющегося союза ни... ни: не читает ни книг, ни газет.

> В некоторых устойчивых сочетаниях: н**е играет роли, не производит впечатления, не обращает внимания, не уделяет внимания, не приносит ущерба, не придает значения, не вызывает сомнения, не принимает участия  и т. д. А также: не говоря (не сказав) худого слова; не сводить глаз с кого-чего-л.; не находить себе места; плетью обуха не перешибешь.**

Когда нужен винительный падеж?

> Если отрицание не стоит не при глаголе, а при другом слове: **не очень люблю стихи, не всегда читает книги, не вполне усвоил предмет (ср.: люблю стихи, но не очень; читает книги, но не всегда; усвоил предмет, но не вполне).**
>   Если при глаголе кроме данного существительного должно быть еще одно зависимое существительное или прилагательное: **он не считает книгу интересной; не прочитал статью за вечер; не обеспечили регион электроэнергией; Разве вы не считаете эту практику полезной?**
>    Если существительное относится к инфинитиву, отделенному от глагола с отрицанием другим инфинитивом: он не хочет начинать писать мемуары (ср. он не хочет писать мемуаров и мемуары).

При наличии в предложении местоимений, указывающих на определенность объекта: Эту песню не задушишь, не убьешь; он не решил эту задачу (ср.: он не решал задач); Ростов, не желая навязывать свое знакомство, не пошел в дом (Л. Толст.).
    При наличии после существительного придаточного предложения со словом который: Он не прочитал книгу, которую я ему дал.
    При одушевленном существительном или при имени собственном: Со времени моего кондукторства я не люблю Лесную улицу (Пауст.); Но Суровцев уже понимал, что уйти, не повидав Веру, не в силах (Чак.).

Если отрицание входит в состав частицы **едва не, чуть не, чуть-чуть не:** >Едва не уронил стакан; Чуть не пропустил трамвай; Чуть было не потерял билет.

> В собственно отрицательных предложениях типа Некому показать работу; негде опубликовать статью.
>       В некоторых устойчивых сочетаниях: Не морочь мне голову; Не скаль зубы.

В остальных случаях существительные в описываемых конструкциях обычно можно использовать в форме и родительного падежа, и винительного падежа.

Какой падеж в этих конструкциях использовался раньше – родительный или винительный?

Прежде при глаголах с отрицанием почти всегда употреблялся родительный падеж. «Русская грамматика» пишет: «Единая старая норма обязательного родительного падежа при глаголах с отрицанием в современном языке под влиянием разговорной речи не выдерживается: во многих случаях употребление винительного падежа не только предпочитается, но и является единственно правильным».

> Строгая обязательность родительного падежа при глаголе с отрицанием подвергалась сомнениям уже в XIX веке. Возражая критику, А. С. Пушкин писал: «Стих "Два века ссорить не хочу" критику показался неправильным. Что гласит грамматика? Что действительный глагол, управляемый отрицательною частицею, требует уже не винительного, а родительного падежа. Например: я не пишу стихов. Но в моем стихе глагол ссорить управляем не частицею не, а глаголом хочу. Ergo правило сюда нейдет. Возьмем, например, следующее предложение: Я не могу вам позволить начать писать... стихи, а уж конечно не стихов. Неужто электрическая сила отрицательной частицы должна пройти сквозь всю эту цепь глаголов и отозваться в существительном? Не думаю» (из статьи «Опровержение на критики», 1830).

[Использованная литература:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters)

Граудина Л. К., Ицкович В. А., Катлинская Л. П. Словарь грамматических вариантов русского языка. –3-е изд., стер. М., 2008.
    Русская грамматика / Под ред. Н. Ю. Шведовой. М., 1980.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, простите, ни о чем.

> Разве падеж дополнения не должен зависеть только от семантического отношения с глаголом?

А он, падеж, и зависит ***только*** от семантического отношения. Только не ***однозначно***, как вы неявно предполагаете. А это уже совсем другое жело, причин для такой неоднозначности может быть вагон и маленькая тележка, никакого нарушения базовых концепций грамматики (ни русской, ни общей) тут не просматривается.

Вот почему оно так, это можно исследовать. Видимо, история очень древняя, еще Пушкин в своих заметках - по поводу неприятия критиками его фразы "два века ссорить не хочу" - удивлялся непониманию этого факта двойственности падежа при отрицании глагола. Там, правда, очень частный случай обсуждается, поэтому цитату не привожу, но сам факт пристального внимания к падежу дополнения при отрицании глагола имеет место.